# Instances in Application variable

Tags: c#, performance, application-variables

Is it correct to instantiate classes and save them in Application variables to then use them and not have to instantiate them in each request?

For example: Instanciate a DbContext and use it directly from de Application variable every time I need.

And this means a real improvement in performance?

In the global asa:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
    Application["db"] = new Models.dbContext();
    }
```

Using then:

```
    db = (dbContext)HttpContext.Current.Application["db"];
```

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve]?

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Microsoft recommends: "When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request."
More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`DbContext`s should almost always be instantiated and discarded as needed. Connection-pooling and various other behind-the-scenes optimizations mean that this is quite efficient. Otoh, if you're using `HttpClient`, you should probably aim to create a single one for all calls (as it can't perform connection keep-alive otherwise). It's up to you whether you store in an "Application" variable or just as a global static. But HttpClient is the exception - unless you need to maintain state for the lifetime of your application, or there's some very implementation-specific reason, there are good reasons to avoid having variables with global scope and/or lifetime.